# Why does mirror modifiers mirrors on the same side of object that is to be mirrored?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

the image displayed is mirrored one but it is mirrored on the same side of the object that i want it to be mirrored on the other side of the axis

[image: 1]]

I just added mirror modifiers from modifiers option in the properties .

I even tried duplicating and adding mirror from the tools , it somewhat works but there is not merge limit and came to know it isn't mirroring properly...because moving half part of the character doesn't make sense to the half mirrored one....morevoer joining and merging those two disables mirror modifiers

[image: 2]]

otherwise just mirroring it from the tools panel makes half part to disappear

[image]

Comment: Your model is probably rotated. Use Ctrl+A (apply) then choose "rotation"

Comment: You are mirroring along the wrong axis (changed in modifier properties) and your object origin is supposed to be where you want the mirror axis. You could probably fix both issues by applying rotation and location.

Comment: In the modifier you can choose which axis to mirror. But the problem you have is that the object's origin is not placed correctly (see the orange dot where the arrows are that is the object's origin). The mirror modifier uses the origin as the center from which it mirrors the rest of the geometry.